# Get TD to display below on small screen

Tags: html, css

Here is a simplified version of my problem:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        *[class=col_split] { width: 100% !important; float: left !important; text-align: left !important; padding: 0 !important;}

    }

    </style>

<div style="width:200px;">
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="col_split" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:red;"> left</td>
    <td class="col_split" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:yellow;"> right</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Trying to get the "left box" to display below the "right box" when viewed on a small screen, but stay on the left when viewed at full size.

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: use `bootstrap` a css framework for responsive design.

Comment: This is actually for an email. Bootstrap isn't an option, thank you though.